# What RPG is this site's banner artwork from?

Tags: discussion, design

This site's theme includes artwork of cyborgs firing lasers at a dragon.

I could have sworn that it looked like it came from the RPG Rifts, but a quick Google image search for Rifts artwork isn't turning anything up.

This leads me to wonder what, if any, game the artwork in this site's banner is from. Does anyone know?